# How do I use a file with numbers on each line as an input (not a .txt file), do some calculations, then write the results into another file in pascal?

Tags: file-handling, pascal, calculation

I am trying to make a program that will take a file called "root.inp" (file contains 3 integers) as its input, with each integer in a separate line, and then perform the operation shown in picture:

[image: math operation]

(a, b, c are integers in said input file, s is the result)
After that, I want to be able to write whatever is inside S into a new file called "root.out". But after some time, I cannot find a solution to this. Here's what I've tried

```
program Formula;
type
  input = record
    firstnum: integer;
    secondnum: integer;
    thirdnum: integer;
  end;
  output = record
    sum: real;
  end;
var 
  f: file of input;
  p: file of output;
  S: real;
  a, b, c: integer;
begin
  assign (f, 'root.inp');
  reset (f);
  while not eof(f) do;
  begin
    read (f,input);
    a := input.firstnum;
    b := input.secondnum;
    c := input.thirdnum;
    S := (a*a + b*b + c*c) / (a*b*c) + sqrt(a*b*c);
  end;
  close (f);
  assign (p, 'root.out');
  rewrite(p);
  output.sum := S;
  write(p, output);
  close(p);
end.
```

After executing, the 'root.out' file is completely blank, but the program did not show any error while compiling. I cannot find a cause for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the semicolon after `while not eof (f) do` - this should be removed. The semicolon prevents the loop from running. Also, what is `file of input` and `input.firstnum`? Standard Pascal would have three separate `read` commands, one for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variables of the type input and output, and use them for reading and writing, rather than the type names.

P.S. input and output are predefined identifiers in Pascal's runtime library, better avoid them.